Looking for lightweight WYSIWYG code highlighting recommendations for rails 8 / importmaps?
I realize this has been asked before but all of the questions I've seen are pretty old and out of date. I just updated my rails app to rails 8 with importmaps and thought I'd see if anyone had any recommendations for light weight gems or js packages for WYSIWYG code highlighting that are easy to implement in rails 8 with importmaps?
Exact use case is I have a text area that is a form field where a user can type in some code and I just want some super basic syntax highlighting. No validation or anything needed really.
I was using the ace editor for this pre upgrade, but having some difficulty with adding it using importmaps instead of webpacker. Would love some suggestions for either getting that to work or something similar please, thanks!
